# SqlDataAdapter#Fill: `SelectCommand.connection` property has not been initilized

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sqldataadapter

I am making a Student Management System for our thesis. When I click the login button after I put the username and password, this error shows up in `da.Fill(dt)`:

> **InvalidOperationException was unhandled**
>
> `Fill`: `SelectCommand.connection` property has not been initilized.

[image: Error screenshot]

Here is my code in login button

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    cs = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=demo;Integrated Security=True"
    con = New SqlConnection(cs)
    Dim username As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim password As String = TextBox2.Text

    cmd = New SqlCommand("select username,password from login where 
    username='" + TextBox1.Text + "'and password'" + TextBox2.Text + "' ")
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)

    If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
        name = TextBox1.Text
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful", "success!", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        content.Show()

    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid Login Information!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

When I click the login button I should get to the home page.

This is the login:

[image: Login screenshot]

and this is the home:

[image: Home page]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited your question to quote the error message as text. Also in the title I put the more detailed error message. It is important to enter text literally instead of showing images of text, so they are searchable and accessible. I also embedded the images, although the final two are not that useful for those looking into your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry this is my first time asking question here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which connection to use in your command.

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("select username,password from login where 
username='" + TextBox1.Text + "'and password'" + TextBox2.Text + "' ", con)
```

Please note, you are concatenating string to build your SQL Query.  This is VERY unsecure.  This lead to SQL Injection!  Please at least double quote in string variable, and check int variable that are variable.  But I strongly suggest you to use parametrized variable (See sp_executeSql).

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("select username,password from login where 
username='" + TextBox1.Text.replace("'", "''") + "'and password'" + TextBox2.Text.replace("'", "''") + "' ", con)
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments and explanations in-line.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim cs = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=demo;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim Exists As Boolean
    'The Using block ensures that your database objects are closed and disposed
    'even if there is an error.
    Using con = New SqlConnection(cs)
        'All you need to know is if the record exists. You do not need to return
        'the values you just entered.
        'Pass the connection to the constructor of the command
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand("If Exists (Select username, password From login Where 
username=@User and password = @Password;", con)
            'Use parameters. It not only helps protect your database against SQL Injection but
            'simplifies your SQL statement
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            'You do not need a data adapter or data table for this
            'Use execute scalar when you are returning a single value
            con.Open()
            Exists = CBool(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    If Exists Then
        Name = TextBox1.Text
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful", "success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        content.Show()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login Information!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Never store passwords as plain text.